# How to convert Putty registry entry to known_hosts format?

Tags: windows-registry, putty, known-hosts

Using Putty, I connected to a remote host. As this was a first time me doing so, as expected, ssh key was added.

Google helped me find registry entry, but it is not in a known_hosts format.

How can I take that entry and transform it into the known_hosts format please?

Comment: It probably would be a lot easier to just use [ssh-keyscan](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keyscan) on your *nix box to generate a know known_hosts file.  But +1 anyway.  I suspect converting it would probably involve taking the base16 value from the registry and converting to to base64, which seems to be the format in known_hosts.  But there must be some other changes required also.

Comment: It seems @Zoredache is probably correct.  At least according to the [source code](http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty/sshrsa.c?view=markup#l365) the host fingerprint should be compatible with OpenSSH.